# Base64 encoding for post in WebView

Tags: android, webview, base64, android-webview

I am facing a problem with the encoding of a string. First of all, let me explain the context:

I need to make a post and load the content in a webView. For this requirement I need to use webView.postUrl(String url, byte[] postData).

I saw a lot of examples using this method along with EncodingUtils.getBytes("stringToEncode","base64").

The good news is that this works for me. The bad news is that this class is deprecated and you need to add the next code to the gradle file:

```
android {
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}
```

I would like to avoid this and use the way it should be.

As far as I know the replacement for this deprecated class is android.util.Base64.

I tried the next codes without success:

```
webView.postUrl("url", Base64.encode("paramsToEncode".getBytes(),Base64.DEFAULT));

webView.postUrl("url", Base64.encode("paramsToEncode".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8),Base64.DEFAULT));
```

According to the documentation of [EncodingUtils](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/util/EncodingUtils.html#getBytes(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)):

> Converts the specified string to a byte array. If the charset is not
>   supported the default system charset is used. Parameters: data - the
>   string to be encoded charset - the desired character encoding Returns:
>   The resulting byte array.

And the documentation for [Base64](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Base64.html#encode(byte[],%20int)):

> input byte: the data to encode flags  int: controls certain features of
>   the encoded output. Passing DEFAULT results in output that adheres to
>   RFC 2045. Returns byte[]

So I do not know what I am doing wrong. If you struggled with this kind of problem I would appreciate some comments :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why your example doesn't work, but the below code seems to be working for me:

```
webView.postUrl(url, urlParams.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
```

Comment: Though it is not the answer to my question, it is the answer to my problem! Thanks.